# controls not being displayed

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I have two similar methods to add a user control to a panel as needed. However, upon attempting to add, the method is called and completed, but does not add the user control to the form. While attempting various different ways of adding the user control, one time I could move the initial user control around and it would move to leave space for another user control, but the user control was not visible.

Edit: the initial add method (addInitialItemGroupTest) does work

```
Public Sub addItemGroupTest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Console.WriteLine(Me.GetType.ToString() + "||" + System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod.ToString())
        Dim item_block_new As New ucItemsetItemBlock
        ' item_block_new.Visible = True
        '  item_block_new.Dock = DockStyle.Top
        item_block_new.flpMain.Name = (10 + item_set.blocks.Count()).ToString
        item_block_new.BringToFront()
        frm.flpItemBlocks.Controls.Add(item_block_new)
        '   item_block_new.Show()
        AddHandler item_block_new.flpMain.Click, AddressOf addItemToItemBlock
    End Sub

    Public Sub addInitialItemGroupTest()
        Console.WriteLine(Me.GetType.ToString() + "||" + System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod.ToString())
        Dim item_block As New ucItemsetItemBlock
        '  item_block.Dock = DockStyle.Top
        item_block.flpMain.Name = (10 + item_set.blocks.Count()).ToString
        item_block.BringToFront()
        frm.flpItemBlocks.Controls.Add(item_block)
        AddHandler item_block.flpMain.Click, AddressOf addItemToItemBlock
        '   item_block.Sh
    End Sub

    Public Sub showEditor()
        frm = New frmItemsetEditor
        frm.TopLevel = False
        frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
        If frm.Location.X < 0 Then
            frm.Location = New Point(0, frm.Location.Y)
        End If
        If frm.Location.Y < 0 Then
            frm.Location = New Point(frm.Location.X, 0)
        End If
        frm.Show()
        addItems()
        If id > 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine("loading item set")
            For Each item_block In item_set.blocks
                frm.flpItemBlocks.Controls.Add(item_block)
            Next
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("creating item set")
            item_set = New LeagueItemSet
            addInitialItemGroupTest()
            ' addInitialItemGroup()
        End If
        AddHandler frm.btnAddItemGroup.Click, AddressOf addItemGroupTest
        loadUserControl()
        frm.pnlItemSetUserControl.Controls.Add(uc)
        frm.flpItemBlocks.BringToFront()
        AddHandler uc.btnAddUpdate.Click, AddressOf updateSetting

    End Sub

   Private Sub btnCreateItemset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreateItemset.Click
        Parent.AccessibleDescription = "status:Loading: Itemset Creation Wizard"
        rgoism.addSetting()
        rgoism._Settings.Last.frm.Parent = Me.Parent
        rgoism._Settings.Last.frm.Location = New Point(Convert.ToInt32((Parent.Size.Width / 2) - (rgoism._Settings.Last.frm.Size.Width / 2)), Convert.ToInt32((Parent.Size.Height / 2) - (rgoism._Settings.Last.frm.Size.Height / 2)))
        rgoism._Settings.Last.frm.BringToFront()
        Me.Hide()
        Parent.AccessibleDescription = "status:Ready"
    End Sub
```

Comment: `frm.Show()` won't work on a form that is TopLevel false.  You essentially made your frmItemsetEditor a UserControl. frm needs to be added to a container's Control collection.

Comment: The form does display and other controls added to the form work correctly. I believe we add it somewhere else in the code, I could be wrong though. I can test the theory

Comment: I can only go by the code you post, and I couldn't find a `...Controls.Add(frm)`

Comment: That's fair. You actually may be right from the beginning (imagine that). Sorry, I am pretty terrible with GUI controls and my partner handles it. I should have just made it a user control in the beginning. Anyway, I added the portion where we add the form but we don't actually place it into a container since I moved the editor previously. He's changing the code now and hopefully it works.

Comment: Nope, we do add it to pnlMain and then show it...

Answer (score 0):

I kept debugging for nearly 12 hours straight. While nearly falling asleep I entered a bunch of console.writeline() into a method to test it since I have been lost. Next thing I know, it is adding visible user controls to the form. I just need to test them and make sure they're unique but I am too tired. I have no idea how it works now since I did not intentionally change any lines of code. Maybe I just lucked out and changed the right line of code by accident. I did comment out and back in a few lines as well. I am completely and utterly lost but it works now.